# Glassfish v4.0 cannot work on Mac OSX 10.6.8 + JDK 7.0 U40

Tags: macos, github, java-7, osx-leopard, glassfish-4

I had been using 2010 Macbook Pro for a while and had updated the Mac OSX to the latest version, and I had been suffering the slow speed for a long time. So last night I googled and do some cleanup , such as fix disk permissions, but the Mac was still slow. And someone suggest to re-install MacOSX.

I was thinking it was the new version of Mac OSX's problem, I had the same kind of problems happen on the 1st version IPad either.

After I reinstalled, the computer became much more faster. But I encountered the following problems:

1. JDK 7 DMG does not support OSX 10.6.8, but ONLY OSX 10.7+
2. Github official client does not support OSX 10.7+

Gooooooogled again and again, to solve the 1st problem, there are mainly to suggestions:
A. Using PackageMaker to remove the OSX version condition.
B. Using a tool Pacifist to open the pkg file inside the DMG file downloaded from official.

Since I have PackageMaker installed on Mac OSX, so I choosed A.
Open it with PackageMaker, remove the limitation, and build it again, I installed with the new pkg file successfully at:
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home

And then set JAVA_HOME on ~/.bash_profile.

Then I download the glassfish 4.0 multi-language version, unzipped, and start-domain successfully. and finally the problem killed me for now.

After glassfish v4 started, I try to login into web console at:

```
http://localhost:4848
```

then glassfish server instance "dies", the java process of glassfish is still there, but without any response, the web console starting icon keeps rolling all the time. And there are no error logs created, and the "generated" directory is not generated.

2013-10-15 14:05:20.928 java[797:903] *** NSInvocation: warning: object 0x1083c8390 of class 'ThreadUtilities' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
2013-10-15 14:05:20.930 java[797:903] *** NSInvocation: warning: object 0x1083c8390 of class 'ThreadUtilities' does not implement doesNotRecognizeSelector: -- abort
Command start-domain failed.

That is the 1st problem.

The 2nd problem is about github. Since github official does not support OSX 10.6.8, I found an old installer with version 1.0.3. I installed this version, with one ONLY problem for now, I cannot login into github with username and password,no error responses, just no responding, I suffered this once I was on Windows. But I can work with clicking the "Clone into Desktop" button on github.com.

Can someone help me out? I am working on JDK7 based projects.

Why everybody is leaving Snow Leopard, and does not support it anymore, but old Mac computers should be die without working software after 2~3 years, just 2~3 years. And OS upgrade to nex t level will DOWNGrade the performance. Why this things happen?
Is it the oracle from god?

Comment: I found glassfish encountered the following error the same problem with jvisualvm

Comment: you saved me a lot of trouble. And I agree that it's a dirty trick to stop supporting 3 year old hardware just to force people to buy more.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error (NSInvocation...), on my 2006 Macbook Pro (OS X 10.6.8), onto which I had installed JDK7 to develop a Java/GWT application in Eclipse Kepler.  After searching around, I learned that one possible solution was to downgrade to JDK 1.7.0u25 (instead of update 40 or higher), so I installed that version alongside 1.7.0u45 (which I already had), and that fixed the problem.  So I would recommend installing that version of the JDK and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: Thank you Jeff, but I installed 10.7.x for the old computer and I changed to a SSD, it's OK now.