# Java Jenkins.war error

Tags: java, jenkins, osx-snow-leopard

I install jenkins on my mac os X 10.6.8, after successfully install jenkins, I browse it in the browser with the default address http://localhost:8080  but the tomcat page display not the jenkins home page.  I read the documentaion on jenkins that it will need to execute command java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=8080

When execute  command 
**java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=8080**

having this error

> 2016-09-15 22:50:56.106 java[46344:a07] *** NSInvocation: warning: object 0x1160db440 of class 'ThreadUtilities' does not implement doesNotRecognizeSelector: -- abort
>       Trace/BPT trap

I don't know what is wrong, please help.

Thanks,
dave

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19372939/glassfish-v4-0-cannot-work-on-mac-osx-10-6-8-jdk-7-0-u40

It looks like the same problem. They solved it by installing a separate java version.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to deploy Jenkins out of the box, just go to:

localhost:8080/html

Select you jenkins.war and thats it.

Just be sure you can deploy files with that size.

You can follow up this link:

https://maxrohde.com/2011/04/27/large-war-file-cannot-be-deployed-in-tomcat-7/